# Can't set editorState in draft.js (it appears immutable but with no error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I've got content saved to a DB using convertToRaw that I'm trying to load back into a draft.js editor to enable a user to re-edit the content.

The draft.js editor is contained within a [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) based component that is shown when the user clicks 'edit' on the piece of content.  This is important because the Modal (and the Editor) are not re-instantiated, they're just shown and hidden.

The Editor is initiated once in the (ES6) class constructor simply using:

```
this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()}
```

When the user clicks 'edit' I load the raw content from the the DB, then I've tried loading my raw content into the Editor using a number of variants of:

```
const contentState = convertFromRaw(rawContent)
const newEditorState = EditorState.push(this.state.editorState, contentState);
this.setState({editorState: newEditorState})
```

But while newEditorState clearly contains the correct content, `this.setState({editorState: newEditorState})` seems to have no effect at all on the state of the component (or the Editor).

How am I meant to set new state for the Editor? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
On further investigation, it is clearly just `this.setState({editorState: newEditorState})` which is failing just for the Editor component.

I've tested it by setting a test state property and updating it successfully, while the editorState remains unchanged.

To test this fully, in my constructor I've initialised state with test values using:

```
this.state = { 
    editorState:EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText('Hello')),
    testVal: 'Test Val 1'
}
```

Then I've written some test code to show how setState works for my test value but not for the draft.js editorState:

```
const newEditorState = EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText('Goodbye'))
console.log('Before setState')
console.log('newEditorState: ' + newEditorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText());
console.log('editorState: ' + this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText());
console.log('testVal: ' + this.state.testVal);

this.setState({editorState: newEditorState, testVal: 'Test Val 2'}, function(){
    console.log('After setState')
    console.log('editorState: ' + this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText());
    console.log('testVal: ' + this.state.testVal);
});
```

The console output looks like:

```
Before setState
    newEditorState: Goodbye
    editorState: Hello
    testVal: Test Val 1
After setState
    editorState: Hello
    testVal: Test Val 2
```

I can't see why the draft.js editorState isn't being updated when the testVal is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found out what the problem was.

I was setting the focus to the Editor immediately *after* trying to call `setState()`.

i.e. I was calling `focus()` on the Editor, by moving the `focus()` call to *before* I try to setState, it all worked.  Clearly accepting focus has an effect on the editorState.

Answer (score 2):

I did it with the following in my project

```
const blocks = convertFromRaw(props.rawBlocks);
editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(blocks, null);
```

Comment: Thanks @jiang-YD my problem seems to be in this.setState, it just doesn't appear to be updating the state at all.